# $localStorage array select with ng-options not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

This is my code. i am using $localStorage for pushing an object into array. when i clicking the button the object is pushed properly and splicing the same same object again click on the same button. $localStorage.tableArray assign to the $scope.Storage for dropdown list. Drop down list coming good when the button action done.

My problem is the $scope.$storage having two items. if i refresh the page dropdown list not came.
if i pushing or splicing action performed on the buttons drop down list coming good.

please help how to get $scope.$storage items into the dropdown list when refreshing the page.
I Create a plunker regarding this. check once

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<a class="btn {{table.btnClass}} btn-success" ng-repeat="table in tablelist" ng-click="getTable(table)" style="padding-left:1px">{{table.tablename}}</a>
<select ng-options="table.tablename as table.tablename for table in $storage" ng-model="table.tablename"><option value="">---select table---</option></select>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ngStorage"]);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$localStorage,$filter) {
            $scope.tablelist = [{ "tablename": "t1" }, { "tablename": "t2" },{ "tablename": "t3" },{ "tablename": "t4" }]
        if ($localStorage.tableArray === undefined) {
            $localStorage.tableArray = []
        }
        if ($localStorage.tableslist === undefined) {
            $localStorage.tableslist = []
        }

        angular.forEach($scope.tablelist, function (list, $index) {
            var found = $filter('filter')($localStorage.tableArray, { tablename: list.tablename }, true);
            if (found.length) {
                $scope.tablelist[$index].btnClass = found[0].btnClass;
            }
        });


        $scope.getTable = function (table) {

            table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-danger" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger"
            var exists = false;
            angular.forEach($localStorage.tableArray, function (list, $index) {
                if ((list.tablename == table.tablename)) {
                    console.log(list.tablename)
                    console.log(table.tablename)
                    exists = true;
                    $localStorage.tableArray.splice($index, 1)
                    $localStorage.tableslist.splice($index, 1)
                    $scope.$storage= $localStorage.tableArray;
                    console.log( $scope.$storage)

                    return false
                }
            });
            if (!exists) {
                $localStorage.tableslist.push(table)
                $localStorage.tableArray = $localStorage.tableslist;
                $scope.$storage = $localStorage.tableArray
                console.log($localStorage.tableArray)
                table.color = "red"
            }
        }
    });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0RpAGVR5ZpVFMvmmxipu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you So Much @Fidel90. working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want your dropdown list to be initialized on refresh  with the stored value from your localstorage.

Adding below line in controller works for me:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.tableArray
```

Check [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPiLnDlVvaZuHUqysDrU?p=preview)